# Unable to compile Emacs auto-complete. Dependency on popup

Tags: emacs, autocomplete

I just git cloned `auto-complete` from GitHub. When I typed

> make

I got:

```
emacs -Q -L . -batch -f batch-byte-compile auto-complete.el auto-complete-config.el

In toplevel form:
auto-complete.el:49:1:Error: Cannot open load file: popup

In toplevel form:
auto-complete-config.el:31:1:Error: Cannot open load file: popup
make: *** [byte-compile] Error 1
```

I didn't see anything in the `auto-complete` documentation that says that I have to install `popup`. I don't remember running into this problem before. Is this a new dependency? Is `popup` a package that is required by `auto-complete`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you use Emacs 24 (which you probably should by now) you can use the command `M-x package-install` and install auto-complete through there. This will install it correctly and is the best method of installing packages.

`popup.el` should have been included with your copy of auto-complete though, if not check here https://github.com/auto-complete/popup-el to get the appropriate copy.

To enable packages you can add something like this to your `.emacs`:

```
(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives
             '("melpa" . "http://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/") t)
(package-initialize)
(setq url-http-attempt-keepalives nil)
```

The last line is simply to keep the downloads of large packages from timing out sometimes.

Comment: Thanks Jesus. I am running 24.2.1 and when I tried to install `auto-complete` with `M-x package-install` I get `No match`. Any thoughts why?

Comment: @user273158 You might need to do `require ('package)` in your .emacs or evaluate that in a buffer somewhere and then call `(package-initialize)`.

Comment: Thanks! What is `melpa` exactly? I have other sources in `package-archives` such as `ELPA`, `gnu` and `marmalade`. Where can I find more information about these sources, and how do you know which package is available at which source?

Comment: @user273158 They're different sources for packages, `MELPA` is just a big one that isn't included by default. You can do a quick google search for more package sources but I just stick with the defaults and `MELPA`.

Comment: Thanks. By the way, I added all these sources and tried re-loading Emacs a few times, but I still don't see `auto-complete` listed in the list of packages that I can install (I am using Helm, which shows a list of candidates for many Emacs commands). Either way, even if I try typing `auto-complete` in full, it returns `no match` in `M-x package-install`.

Comment: @user273158 Try `M-x package-referesh-contents`

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem than you did, find you post struglgle a little before to find why it wasn't working: **I had forgot to initate the submodules...** reason why Make wasn't finding popup and crashing

so to solve it, go in your autocomplete repo and run

```
git submodule update --init
```

this will build the three lib you need to compile autocomplete